# how to access calling object in react transform-class-properties function calls

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

For the react plugin transform-class-properties you can call a function without doing a bind, but using the "this" object then calls the parent class object and not the calling obj.

So for this example.  The original code calls a function with an input variable and updates the select.

```
<Select
    ...
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(variable)}
     ...
/>

handleChange(lookupKey, event) => {
    ...
    this.set(value, 'form');
}
```

With the transform-class-properties version it does not work as the "this" object is for the parent class object.

```
<Select
    ...
    onChange={this.handleChange(variable)}
     ...
/>

handleChange = (lookupKey) => (event) => {
    ...
    // no longer works
    this.set(value, 'form');
}
```

Is it calling object passed or accessible like the original without having to know where it is in props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns, I don't think I provided enough of an example to make sense for an answer, but I was able to sort out my problem.

What was happening is that the bind was assigning the first variable to "this".

```
<Select
    ...
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(obj, variable)}
    ...
/>

handleChange(lookupKey, event) => {
    ...
    this.set(value, 'form');
}
```

with transform-class-properties version this does not happen.  All I needed to do is set the first variable as the first variable of the calling function and then use it instead of "this".

```
<Select
    ...
    onChange={this.handleChange(obj, variable)}
    ...
/>

handleChange = (obj, lookupKey) => (event) => {
    ...
    obj.set(value, 'form');
}
```